# Node.js/Express static assets connection refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have just deployed my Express app to a production server and I'm no longer being served my static assets.

My assets are in `/public` and I call the static middleware like so:

```
// config.root => /var/www
app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
```

When I spin up my site, the stylesheets aren't coming through and I'm seeing:

```
GET http://--- redacted ---/scripts/main.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

If I open up the stylesheet URL I can see it no problem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: press F12 and view the network tab to see what's up, it could be anything. but i'm going to guess that it's served from a different domain name and thus the browser applies CORS protection?

Comment: I can't really find anything in the network tab. The request/referral IP addresses and ports are the same. The connection for this file was stalled after 32 ms.

Comment: You mentioned you can see your stylesheets if you browse to their URLs manually. Can you also see your main.js code if you browse to `http://--- redacted ---/scripts/main.js`?

Comment: Yes I can. I can view any of the missing assets (which throw that "CONNECTION_REFUSED" error) by going to their URLs manually.

Comment: what is a 'referral ip' ? the machine making the request? we really can't help wihtout more information. the response headers from the F12 console would be a good start

Comment: There are no response headers. http://i.imgur.com/d94olsl.png http://i.imgur.com/aoK8CDf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug (undefined function) in one of my middleware functions. Check your logs, people!